# S3 temporary signed url with custom header without modifying object metadata to disk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I have a bucket with arbitrarily named files and a ruby script that generates a signed URL that expires in 2 days but I need to add a content disposition header to correct the file name to the desired format.

abritrarily (with a primary key from a database) to prevent filename conflict

is it possible to change the URL to make it add the content disposition header without modifying the files `content-disposition` header and saving it on the bucket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the instance method [url_for()](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/S3Object.html#url_for-instance_method) of class [AWS::S3::S3Object](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/S3Object.html) from the [AWS SDK for Ruby](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/) to generate the pre-signed URL for your [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) objects, the optional `options` hash allows you to specify *Additional options for generating the URL*, amongst those the desired `content-disposition` header:

> :**response_content_disposition** (String) — Sets the Content-Disposition
>   header of the response when performing an HTTP GET on the returned
>   URL.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone was looking for JavaScript example:

```
s3.getSignedUrl(
  'getObject',
  {
    Bucket: 'foo',
    Key: 'bar',
    ResponseContentDisposition: 'attachment; filename="bar"'
  },
  (error, signedURL) => {
    console.log(signedURL);
  }
);
```